# Angular 4 with custom request header

Tags: angular, http, angular4-httpclient

Working in Angular 4 application.
Created http interceptor for sending request to the api.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestInteceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    loginUserName = "";
    constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


        if (environment.Authentication == 1) {           
            // add a custom header


            const newRequest = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('userName', '11111')});
            return next.handle(newRequest);
        }

        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

I have configured this interceptor in my app.module.ts as below

```
providers: {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpRequestInteceptor,
      multi: true
    }
```

Here I am trying to pass a custom header value in the get request, but I don't see my header value is passing in the request when I look at the network tab in the chrome.

My Asp.Net Web api code could be.

```
HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
string    user = app.Context.Request.Headers.GetValues("userName").First();
```

I am getting user name value in the web.api code when I access the url from postman & advanced reset client.

But I am not getting the header value when I access the same api url from Angular 4 application.

Please help me where I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setHeaders https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#clone:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestInteceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    loginUserName = "";
    constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


        if (environment.Authentication == 1) {           
            // add a custom header


            const newRequest = req.clone({
              setHeaders: { 'userName': '11111' }
            });
            return next.handle(newRequest);
        }

        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: The values are getting passed to my service. Do you have any idea how I can get the custom header value(11111) from my request

Comment: in angular ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869046/angular-turn-off-json-parser/47869352#47869352