# Angular turn off json parser

Tags: json, angular

The server responses with plain text and angular try to parse json. How do i turn of this behaviour in one component?

```
get(mrn: string): Observable<string> {
    let url: string;
    url = this.Url;
    url = url + '?mrn=' + mrn;
    return this.http.get<string>(url);
  }


download(testobject: Testobject): void {
    this.httpService.get(testobject.mrn)
      .subscribe(ccresult => {
        console.log('ccresult ist: ' + ccresult);
      });
  }
```

Error: error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttp.......

Comment: [Read the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get [HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) object like this:

```
this.http.get<any>(url, { observe: 'response' }).map((res): HttpResponse) => ...);
```